# Factorial in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I decided to write a simple `factorial()` function in JavaScript and ask here for opinions. The idea is to further improve my JavaScript style and learn the best practices. Is there something bad with this code? What can be improved? Any suggestions are welcome.

```
/**
 * Calculates the factorial of a given non-negative finite integer.
 * @param {Number} n
 * @return {Number} factorial
 * @throws TypeError if n is not a Number
 * @throws TypeError if n is a Number but not an integer
 * @throws RangeError if n is a negative integer
 */
function factorial(n) {
    if (typeof n !== "number") {
        throw new TypeError("factorial() expects a number.");
    }
    if (Math.floor(n) !== n) {
        throw new TypeError("factorial() expects an integer.");
    }
    if (n < 0) {
        throw new RangeError("factorial() expects a non-negative number.");
    }

    // 170 is the biggest integer whose factorial does not become Infinity in JavaScript.
    // Therefore, we can improve performance by checking directly.
    // This if statement also handles the important edge case of n === Infinity, which
    // would cause the function to be stuck forever.
    if (n > 170) {
        return Infinity;
    }

    var accumulator = 1;

    for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        accumulator *= i;
    }

    return accumulator;
}
```

Comment: I would use the full error text (the 3rd one) for all cases.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (typeof n !== "number") {
    throw new TypeError("factorial() expects a number.");
}
if (Math.floor(n) !== n) {
    throw new TypeError("factorial() expects an integer.");
}
if (n < 0) {
    throw new RangeError("factorial() expects a non-negative number.");
}
```

First, I discourage manual type and value checks on runtime. They're redundant since the JS engine will emit an error if you operate on the wrong data anyways. It's also runtime overhead as well as unnecessary code.

Often times, developers forward this task to the IDE when writing code. With the right plugins and annotations, the IDE can warn you of incompatible data types and operations. This only prevents writing the API incorrectly though. There's still risk of using the function incorrectly, but that's the consumer's fault, not the API.

```
var accumulator = 1;
```

JS has `let`, the block-scoped version of `var`. It's a good habit to use `let` since in most cases, you'll want block-scoped vars. It also prevents ambiguity of where the variable exists in the code, which usually causes problems (like `var` in `for` or `if`). If I remember correctly, it's because of hoisting that developers started defining `var`s explicitly on the top of the function body to signal that a variable of that name exists in the function.

```
if (n > 170) {
    return Infinity;
}

var accumulator = 1;

for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    accumulator *= i;
}

return accumulator;
```

In the end, the factorial code is just the one above. A shorter version factorials can be done using recursion.

```js
function factorial(n) {
  return n > 170 ? Infinity    // Bail out on 170
    : n == 0 || n == 1 ? 1  // When the answer is just 1
    : n * factorial(n - 1)  // Multiply current with next smallest
}

console.log(factorial(1))
console.log(factorial(2))
console.log(factorial(3))
console.log(factorial(4))
console.log(factorial(5))
```

Comment: Your recursive function will throw `RangeError` when the call stack overflows if the argument is `n < 1`

Comment: When I read this ~9 hours ago I thought the ternary statement looked a bit ugly. Coming back now, I find it is even more so. I find simple if statements for the bounds checking much easier to read.

Comment: *This is a close to perfect implementation of factorial in JS* ? The function does not even work in its current version. @Jonah

Comment: The recursion still fails due to call stack overflow if fractions are passed as argument. eg `factorial(0.1)`. The recursion function should be as simple as possible eg `function factorial (n) {  /* vet n here */ const f = n => n > 1 ? n * f(n - 1) : 1; return f(n | 0); }` Adding bounds checking in the recursion means you repeat the vetting each iteration, while it is only needed once.

Comment: @Gerrit0 It's a matter of taste. The issue I have with `if` statements is the unnecessary visual noise it creates, too much code for something simple. For cases where you 1) only need expressions and 2) the logic is fairly linear and like a lookup, a ternary written this way is much more readable.

Comment: @Blindman67 If the docs tell you to use a positive integer greater than 0, would you stick in a string? No. That's exactly the point of the first section of the answer - You cannot expect all the possible ways the API can break and trying to guard it thouroughly is a futile effort. This is the whole reason why linters and languages like typescript exist, to shift this responsibility to authoring tools, not at runtime. The code already throws an error if the input is wrong, which is sufficient in this case.

Comment: Still this solution suffers from the same problem I highlighted below the other answer @Jonah

Comment: @Joseph If the docs say this and that and it make no sense, I change the docs, not the quality of the code.  2 characters of code will coerce a float to an int  '|0' and will prevent a low level function from potentially blocking the whole page  with an untrappable bug  (Some browsers have tail call optimisation). Javascript is not a type safe language, work with it not against it.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ you are absolutely right -- it's not tail-recursive.  I've removed my previous comments, though I still stand by the ternary part being more readable than `if` statements.

Answer (score 3):

### Type and vetting

There are a few issues with the code, though minor they would make the function more usable.

- Javascript is loosely typed and therefore you should expect that a function's arguments be so as well. If you are passed a string eg `factorial("10")` you throw an error. This is not what I would expect from a javascript function.
- Though debatable, `Infinity` is not the correct result for an input value over 170. It is actually difficult to select an appropriate result for out of range values. I would opt for a `RangeError` for both n > 170 and n < 0
- The correct numeric return for an argument that can not be coerced into a number is `NaN`
- You can only get the factorial of integers, I would thus expect that the function floor the argument for me.
- Good code is efficient in both memory and speed. You can improve the function by removing the iterator variable `i` and use the input argument n in its place and use a while loop.
- Declare var's at the top of the function.

#### Rewrite

Thus I would rewrite your code to the following

```
function factorial (n) {
    var accumulator = 1; 

    if (isNaN(n)) {
        return NaN;
    }

    n |= 0; // this will convert a string to type Number

    if (n > 170 || n < 0 ) { 
        throw new RangeError ("Argument out of range. Arguments range is 0 - 170 inclusive.");
    }

    while (n > 1) { 
        accumulator *= n--;
    }

    return accumulator;
}
```

Though i prefer a different more compact style.

```
function factorial (n) {
    var accumulator = 1;     
    if (isNaN(n)) { return NaN }
    n |= 0; 
    if (n > 170 || n < 0 ) { throw new RangeError ("Argument out of range.Arguments range is 0 - 170 inclusive.") }
    while (n > 1) { accumulator *= n-- }
    return accumulator;
}
```

#### Faster via lookup.

What I don't like about this function is its complexity grows in relationship to the value n. As the range of valid input values is small this function would best be implemented as a lookup table. For speed I would also drop the type checking.

Though you add a slight overhead just after parsing the code all subsequent calls will have the same execution time and be many time faster than calculating the value.

```
const factorial = (() => {
    const f = new Float64Array(171);
    (()=>{
        var i, a = 1;
        f[0] = a;
        for (i = 1; i < 171; i++) { f[i] = a *= i }
    })();
    return (n) => n < 0 || n > 170 ? NaN : f[n | 0];
})();
```

#### Note on recursion.

Though this function is often used as an example of recursion you should avoid recursion in javascript if you are not in control of the calling code. Javascript has a limited call stack, and Tail call optimisation as yet has not been implemented by Chrome, Edge, Firefox. As you can not determine the depth of the call stack at run time any recursive code can indeterminately throw a `RangeError`.

Comment: Why do you prefer to have variable declarations at the top? Isn't it usual to declare variables right before they're initially used?

Comment: Isn't it customary for the RangeError to indicate what the acceptable range is?

Comment: @Snowbody vars are hoisted, putting them at the top gives a better indication of their scope. It also makes it easier to know what variables are being used within the function.. You are right about the range error I will add that.

Comment: The OP wants his function to reject any input which is not a positive integer but your solution accepts floats.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ Yes the solution does, but the OP stated "Any suggestions are welcome." and I consider it a better solution. Why force all code that uses a function to repeat the same thing, just to safely call it. You should not repeat, nor should you need to catch, two signs of bad code. (note the last function does not throw)

Comment: "*You can only get the factorial of integers*" is true, but the factorial function has a standard complex continuation called the gamma function. I can see an argument for evaluating the gamma function if given a non-integral argument, but not for flooring the input.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I did not know that (gamma function). I think the point is being missed. This is javascript, it has a basic type Number that is a 64bit double. To pass an integer directly to a function is not possible (unless you use a typed array) and to have a function that will throw for the slightest rounding error is anoying (I was going to use Math,round but flooring is more like integer behaviour) The function is going to end up being called with the rounding done in the calling code to ensure the integer and avoid the throw. This is pointless repetition!!!

Comment: I'm not at all convinced. If OP wants a factorial function rather than a gamma function and wants it for any practical purpose (as opposed to just as a programming kata) then the primary use case is combinatorics, and calling it with a non-integral value would almost certainly be the result of a bug earlier in the execution. 64-bit doubles have exact representation of 52-bit integers, so it is in fact *very easy* to pass an integer directly to a function.

Comment: @PeterTaylor It is easy to pass an int with certainty `factorial(myNum | 0)` will not throw, while `factorial(myNum)` may throw if there is a rounding error. Javascript tries not to throw Math.sqrt(-2) does not throw, x / 0 does not throw and passing 3.000000001 as an argument rather than 3 should not throw. I would change the non int to return  NaN rather than the (incorrect) TypeError.

Answer (score -1):

One possible way to refactor the different cases you did to check if the input is valid  is by relying on [Number.isInteger()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) function which returns `true` if the argument is an integer.

```
   // This also test if the integer is positive
   if (Number.isInteger(n) && n > 1){
        var accumulator = 1;
        for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            accumulator *= i;
        }
        return accumulator;
   } else {
        // Throws an error for ALL other wrong inputs
        throw new Error("Expected a positive integer value");
   }
```

So your code can be:

```js
function factorial(n) {
   if (n === 0 || n=== 1){ 
        return 1; 
   }
   if (n > 170) {
        return Infinity;
   } 
   if (Number.isInteger(n) && n > 1){
        var accumulator = 1;
        for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            accumulator *= i;
        }
        return accumulator;
   } else {
        throw new Error("Expected a positive integer value");
   }       
}

// Testing
console.log(factorial(0));
console.log(factorial(1));
console.log(factorial(9));
console.log(factorial(170));
console.log(factorial(171));
// All below test will throw an error:
//console.log(factorial("100"));
//console.log(factorial(a));
//console.log(factorial(2.2));
//console.log(factorial(-2));
```

Comment: I'm not sure what point you're trying to make with "*You forgot to test when the input number is zero*". OP's code has the test right here: `for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++)`. It's simpler than your proposed alternative and works just as well.